# Sharing a variable between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have an iPhone app with three pages, each of which allows the user to enter some text. On the final page I want to concatenate all three strings and print it out. I have a `UIViewController` (named `PageXController`) for each page and I am trying to pass variables along to the final page. The method I currently try doesn't quite work. Here is an example:

I begin by declaring a string as an instance variable in `PageThreeController.h`

```
@interface PageThreeController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableString *string;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *string;
```

Next I add the following to `PageOneController.h`,

```
#import "PageThreeController.h"

@interface PageOneController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) PageThreeController *pageThree;
```

In `PageOneController` I then attempt to set the string instance variable on page three;

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender {
    _pageThree = [[PageThreeController alloc] init];
    _pageThree.from = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [_pageThree.from appendString:@"Hello World"];
        NSLog(@"My string is %@ on page one.", _pageThree.from);
}
```

The `NSLog` prints out My string is `'Hello World'` on page one. but when I add the same NSLog on `PageThreeController.m` before concatenating, `'string'` is `NULL`.

It seems that I am making a separate copy of the `pageThreeViewController`. What do I need to do to change the actual value of string on page three? I am really new at this

Comment: `_pageThree.from = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];` is wrong for a start; calling code should not be allocating instance variables.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? How do you switch between view controllers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the value of a variable of a viewcontoller from another viewcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770216/using-the-value-of-a-variable-of-a-viewcontoller-from-another-viewcontroller) or a dozen other answers over there under "Related" ------>

Comment: So where are you meant to allocate the instance variable if the only time it is altered is on a different page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to pass data between ViewControllers is using the AppDelegate, even though
there is other methods .

Method 1 - using AppDelegate.
Add the following line in your Appdelegate.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableString *str;
```

To access the variable from any view controller,

```
 MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

 NSMutableString *Stringdata=appDelegate.str;
```

Method 2 -Specifying objects.
in this method , you can proceed as you are now doing and, just need to specify the 
view controller instance.

let you have are navigating from one controller to another , say FirstController to Second.
Firstcontroller.h

```
@interface FirstController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableString *string;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *string;
```

SecondController.h

```
@interface SecondController : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong,nonatomic) FirstController *firstScreen;
```

Within your implementation of the FirstController, before you navigate to the SecondController ,you have to specify  the instance in SecondController.

in FirstController.m

```
SecondController *nextScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];

nextScreen.firstScreen=self;
```

Then in your SecondController.m , you can simply get the String as

```
_firstScreen.string;
```

Comment: I am trying your method 1. when I print out appDelegate.str in p1 it is null. but when i add appDelegate.str = ((MutableString alloc) init) to it i can print out appDelegate.str in p1. however when I am trying to access it in p3 and print it out i get null. does this have to do with how i allocate? Where am i meant to allocate appDelegate.str?

Comment: Try initiating it in AppDelegate.m within  application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..

Comment: you have to use method 2 for object reference. ie to access the viewcontroller instance  without creating new one.

Comment: I think everything works now. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I can see how App Delegate will be easier for me. I was planing on passing a bool array later on and this will be really useful

Answer (score 0):

Customize your prepareForSegue method in order to pass necessary vars through public properties of these controllers. 
For example:

```
#pragma mark - PreparaForSegue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToDetail"]) {
           YourDestinationController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destinationController.myString = self.myStringToPass;
    }
}
```

Where myString is a public property in YourDestinationController and myStringToPass is a property in your source controller (it could be in private scope)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access it from anywhere, you could store the variable in the AppDelegate. So if you had a variable like this in your AppDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *currentStringToPass;
```

Then you could access it from your ViewControllers by using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    _pageThree = [[PageThreeController alloc] init];
    _pageThree.from = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [app setCurrentStringToPass:@"Hello World"];
        NSLog(@"My string is %@ on page one.", [app currentStringToPass]);
}
```